# how to scroll to a position searched in search bar in custom listview

Tags: android, searchbar

I am developing an app in which i want to search elements from a list-view through search bar.
after that listview move to searched element position automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do that based on your ID value and then

```
   getListView().setSelection(2);
```

2 is a random value here, you can program it into a variable.

If you want the scroll to be smooth:

```
    getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(2);
```

Oh! I assume that you are populating the list view from a Database.